# Write the output of the child in shell and in file error.log

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I attempt to pipe the output of a child, into a file and write it by Father.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int prepare_log(void){
    int fd = open("error.log",
        O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND,
        S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH );
    return fd;
}

void log_stderr(int pipe_ends[], int outfile){
    close(pipe_ends[1]);
    dup2(pipe_ends[0],outfile);
    close(pipe_ends[0]);

}
void child(int pipe_ends[], char* argv[]){
    close(pipe_ends[0]);
    dup2(pipe_ends[1],1);
    close(pipe_ends[1]);
    execvp(argv[0], argv);
}

void bury(){
    int status;
    wait(0);

}

int main(){
    int fd = prepare_log();
    char* argv[] = {"seq", "10", NULL};

    int pipe1[2];
    if(pipe(pipe1) == -1){
        printf("Dont' create Pipe\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0){
        perror("ERROR");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if(pid > 0){
        log_stderr(pipe1, fd);
        bury();
    } else if (pid == 0){
        child(pipe1,argv);
    }
}
```

At the moment I try only to pipe the output of child to father and then write it to a file. 
My final goal is also to display it to the terminal. My idea is to use 3 pipes and redirects the first pipe that we can see in the code, as the input of the 2-nd and 3-rd pipe. Then 
redirect the output of the 2-nd pipe with dup2(pipe2[1],file1) und the 3-rd with dup2(pipe2[1], stdout).

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: Processes are genderless.  s/father/parent/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Program design

The parent process is going to have to read the response from the child, and arrange to write that information twice, once to the log file and once to the terminal.  Or you're going to have to arrange for the output from the child to go to a program like `tee` which writes copies of its input to multiple destinations.

More pipes won't help unless you're using one to redirect the output of the child to `tee`.

#### Closing pipe file descriptors

You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child process.

---

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD` or `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC`.

---

If the parent process will not communicate with any of its children via
the pipe, it must ensure that it closes both ends of the pipe early
enough (before waiting, for example) so that its children can receive
EOF indications on read (or get SIGPIPE signals or write errors on
write), rather than blocking indefinitely.
Even if the parent uses the pipe without using `dup2()`, it should
normally close at least one end of the pipe — it is extremely rare for
a program to read and write on both ends of a single pipe.

Note that the `O_CLOEXEC` option to 
[`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html),
and the `FD_CLOEXEC` and `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC` options to `fcntl()` can also factor
into this discussion.

If you use
[`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html)
and its extensive family of support functions (21 functions in total),
you will need to review how to close file descriptors in the spawned process
([`posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose.html),
etc.).

Note that using `dup2(a, b)` is safer than using `close(b); dup(a);`
for a variety of reasons.
One is that if you want to force the file descriptor to a larger than
usual number, `dup2()` is the only sensible way to do that.
Another is that if `a` is the same as `b` (e.g. both `0`), then `dup2()`
handles it correctly (it doesn't close `b` before duplicating `a`)
whereas the separate `close()` and `dup()` fails horribly.
This is an unlikely, but not impossible, circumstance.

#### Sufficiently fixed code

Here is a fixed version of your program.  The logic in `log_stderr()` is odd; the one thing it doesn't do is write to standard error.  I've modified it so it does read from the pipe and write to both standard output and the log file.  Note that it takes one read but two writes to replicate the information.  Error checking is skimpy to non-existent.  The `bury()` function now reports on the death of a child. The code was saved in `pipe71.c` and compiled to `pipe71`.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static
int prepare_log(void)
{
    int fd = open("error.log",
                  O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND,
                  S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH );
    return fd;
}

static
void log_stderr(int pipe_ends[], int outfile)
{
    char buffer[512];
    int nbytes;
    close(pipe_ends[1]);
    while ((nbytes = read(pipe_ends[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
    {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, nbytes);
        write(outfile, buffer, nbytes);
    }
    close(pipe_ends[0]);
    close(outfile);
}

static
void child(int pipe_ends[], char *argv[])
{
    dup2(pipe_ends[1], 1);
    close(pipe_ends[0]);
    close(pipe_ends[1]);
    execvp(argv[0], argv);
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to execute %s\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static
void bury(void)
{
    int status;
    int corpse;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("%d: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
}

int main(void)
{
    int fd = prepare_log();
    char *argv[] = {"seq", "10", NULL};

    int pipe1[2];
    pipe(pipe1);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid > 0)
    {
        log_stderr(pipe1, fd);
        bury();
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        child(pipe1, argv);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, it does work:

```
$ rm error.log
$ ./pipe71
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
99989: child 99990 exited with status 0x0000
$ cat error.log
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$
```

Comment: Does it mean i should close the both end of the pipes bevor runn the exec in child, but close only the write and of the pipe by the parent, so he still can read?

Comment: Yes, it does mean you need both the `close(pipe_ends[0]);` and `close(pipe_ends[1]);` before `execv()`.  In general, you can run into problems detecting EOF when you don't close all the unused descriptors.  You might be OK in this case; you might not.  But sloppy coding makes it hard to debug why a program is hanging — which is a common symptom of improperly closed pipes.

Comment: The `close(pipe_ends[0]);` that's currently commented out is needed.  It seems curious to connect the read end of the pipe to a file descriptor designated `outfile`.  That is going to cause confusion, partly because it doesn't mean that the information written on the pipe will be automagically written to the output file, and partly because only read operations on the `outfile` file descriptor will work from here onwards.

Comment: I have changed this but it still doesn't work, it doesn't output anything on the terminal and doesn't write on the file. It seems like the pipe doesn't work. When I try to change the order then it writes seq: write error: Bad file descriptor

Comment: I've added workable but imperfect code that produces the output I think you want.